# Split array to minimum subarray containing unique object combinations

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am working on a project in which the client sends us an array having some objects, there can be duplicate objects in the request as well. We determine the duplicate object based on the key called `code`. Here's an example:

```js
[ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 20}, {code:30} ]
```

In the example array above, we have 3 duplicate objects i.e., `{code: 10}`

We need to send this request to a third-party API, which accepts an array as well. The problem is that, in a single request to this API, we can't send duplicate objects. So we need to break this array provided by the client to a subarray, and then send each array to the API.
If we break the sample provided above, we can get

```js
[ [ {code: 10}, {code:20}, code:30} ], [ {code:10} ], [ {code:10} ] ]
```

So, in each of the subarray, we have unique objects (not duplicated)
Also, we have a condition that the very first subarray, should contain all of the unique objects provided in the request by the client.

So, if we have a request from the client something like

```js
[ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code:20}, {code:20}, {code:30} ]
```

then the minimum subarray should be

```js
[ [ {code: 10}, {code: 20}, {code:30} ], [ {code: 10}, {code:20} ], [ {code: 10} ] ]
```

can anyone help me here how can I break the array-like this?
thank you

Comment: I would loop through all the objects and check if it is present in the first minimal array. If not, put it in the first minimal array. If it does exist, check the next. And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple, I found the answer after some fiddling around. We can find the subarray in basically 3 steps

1. Find all the unique objects, and push them to an array, name `unique`
2. Find the difference from the original array
3. repeat, until there is a difference left

```js
const data = [ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code:20}, {code:20}, {code:30} ];

let temp = data;
const subarray = [];
while (temp.length) {
  // find unique
  let unique = [];
  temp.map(x => unique.filter(a => a.code === x.code).length > 0 ? null : unique.push(x));

  // find difference
  const diff = temp.filter(x => !unique.includes(x));

  // store
  subarray.push(unique);
  temp = diff;
}
console.log(subarray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reducer to start with `[[]]` and then attempt to add each item to successive subarrays depending on whether it can find an `i` with the same `code` as the `item`, and then if it can't place it in any subarray, append a new subarray.

```js
const input = [ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 20}, {code:30} ]

const output = input.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  let foundSpace = false;

  accumulator.forEach(subArray => {
    if (!foundSpace && !subArray.find(i => i.code == item.code)) {
      subArray.push(item);
      foundSpace = true;
    }
  })
  if (!foundSpace) {
    accumulator.push([item])
  }
  return accumulator;
}, [[]]);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in `O(n log n)` time complexity. First sort the input array. Then iterate over the array to create output. If the current is same as previous, add it to the next sub array.

```js
let input = [ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 20}, {code:30} ];

input.sort((a, b) => a.code - b.code);

let arr  = [[]];
let idx  = 0;
let prev = -Infinity;

input.forEach(a => {
    if (a.code !== prev) {
         idx = 0;
    } else {
         idx++;
    }
    arr[idx] = arr[idx] || [];
    arr[idx].push(a);
    prev = a.code;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an efficient solution which only parses the original array once. We're going to keep track of the codes we've already encountered in the helper `indices` array. This way we can instantly look up where to put an element.

This way we can simply reduce an array using an accumulator `result`, which will contain all our subarrays.

```js
const arr = [ {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 10}, {code: 20}, {code:30} ];

// helper array to keep track of where to put elements with given code
let indices = [];

// we're going to accumulate our subarrays into the result array
const result = arr.reduce((result, el) => {
  // on first encounter, put in subarray with index 0
  let index = indices[el.code] ?? 0;
  
  // initialise the subarray if not present, and push
  const subArray = result[index] ?? [];
  subArray.push(el);
  
  // put the subarray into the result array
  result[index] = subArray;
  
  // increment the index so next item with this code will go to the next subarray
  indices[el.code] = ++index;
  
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```